# Detect page change Java spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a java spring app.  It has many views.  I got my app started using a template, and I'm trying to understand how exactly it's working.  Basically, i have a single index.html page, and many html files which are used as views with the url looking ilke 'mysite.com/#/view0' .  I want my java code to be able to detect that a use has changed a url (or loaded a different view) without having my javascript code send a rest request to the server.  is this possible?  I haven't posted any code as I'm stumbling through my question here, but if there is any further clarification I can give, please let me know

Comment: In other words, are you asking: "Is it possible for the server to know that the client did something, without making the client send a request to the server?"

Comment: not sure.  If a user clicks a link on my page, and loads another 'view', is this a completely client side event, or  is my server aware of this
?

Comment: If you're using javascript routing (Which I assume because you're using a hash in the url) then no. There's nothing for the server to natively 'detect' without broadcasting an event as hashbangs don't actually 'change' the url... they change the page anchor.

Comment: @EddieB i think that answers my question.  if you put that as an answer, i'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using javascript routing (Which I assume because you're using a hash in the url) then no. There's nothing for the server to natively 'detect' because anchors (<kbd>#</kbd>) don't make a server side request.